# Unable to run python3.8.9 as part of bazel build on Apple-m1

Tags: python-3.x, bazel, apple-m1

bazel installs `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a8b53c99106043b42ff3e67372f6598e/external/pbpy_sc.3.8.9/python-sc.3.8.9_dist/bin/python3` and fails to run it during the build with the following error:

```
dyld[60500]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a8b53c99106043b42ff3e67372f6598e/external/pbpy_sc.3.8.9/python-sc.3.8.9_dist/bin/python3

  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libintl.8.dylib' (no such file)
```

`otool` shows that `python3` depends on `gettext` for some reason.

```
$ otool -L /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a8b53c99106043b42ff3e67372f6598e/external/pbpy_sc.3.8.9/python-sc.3.8.9_dist/bin/python3
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a8b53c99106043b42ff3e67372f6598e/external/pbpy_sc.3.8.9/python-sc.3.8.9_dist/bin/python3:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
```

There is *libintl.8.dylib* in `/opt/local/lib/` but not where python is looking at?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Is is just due to the ARM architecture, e.g. because some binary is only available for x86 or AMD64?

Comment: possible. because M1 is arm64